# Memory allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, csv, memory-leaks, stream

I am facing a memory leak issue in my Node.js code. I am trying to stream read a CSV (sample file in link) file with 100k rows and process each entry in the file. The process struck after some time with a memory allocation error.

> "FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

[sample csv:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SJgTuHAEAV-JZeZvPwSK3NXrWZ_W-lyZj3y6qnOsW0Q/edit?usp=sharing)

**My code sample**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('../config/config');
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const tls = require('../services/tls');

processCSV('crawler', 'sample-csv.csv');
```

**Stream process csv file with 100k entries**

```
async function processCSV (jobName, fileName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let filePath = config.api.basePath + fileName;
    fs.createReadStream(filePath)
        .on('error', () => {
          // handle error
          console.log('error processing csv');
          reject();

        })
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (row) => {
          createJob(jobName, row);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
          // handle end of CSV
          console.log('Finished processing csv');
          resolve(filePath);
        })
  });
}
```

**Validate each url in the csv file**

```
async function createJob (name, data) {
  let {hostname, port, ip} = data;
  let protocol = 'https';
  if (port === 80) {
    protocol = 'http';
  }
  let url = protocol + '://' + hostname;
  try {
    await tls.getHostData(url); // call an external api to get details of hostname
    return url;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}
```

I don't know which function is causing a memory leak.

Comment: Rest of the world doesn't use Indian words like "lakh" and "crore". Please don't use them here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you're calling `createJob()` for every single line in the CSV file and you're probably causing every one of those jobs to be in process and in memory at once.  That can exhaust system resources, particularly if there are a lot of lines in the file.

One idea to solve this would be to adjust the code so that only N `createJob()` operations are "in-flight" at the same time.  Here's one way to do that by pausing the stream when you get to the max number of requests in flight at the same time and then resuming it when there's room for more:

```
async function processCSV (jobName, fileName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let filePath = config.api.basePath + fileName;
    let numConcurrent = 0;
    let paused = false;
    const maxConcurrent = 10;
    let stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
        .on('error', (err) => {
          // handle error
          console.log('error processing csv');
          reject(err);

        })
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (row) => {

          function checkResume() {
              --numConcurrent;
              if (paused && numConcurrent < maxConcurrent) {
                  // restart the stream, there's room for more
                  paused = false;
                  stream.resume();
              }
          }
          ++numConcurrent;
          createJob(jobName, row).then(checkResume, checkResume);
          if (numConcurrent >= maxConcurrent) {
              // pause the stream because we have max number of operations going
              stream.pause();
              paused = true;
          }
        })
        .on('end', () => {
          // handle end of CSV
          console.log('Finished processing csv');
          resolve(filePath);
        })
  });
}


async function createJob (name, data) {
  let {hostname, port, ip} = data;
  let protocol = 'https';
  if (port === 80) {
    protocol = 'http';
  }
  let url = protocol + '://' + hostname;
  try {
    await tls.getHostData(url); // call an external api to get details of hostname
    return url;
  } catch (error) {
    // make sure returned promise is rejected
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Note: This implementation (like the one you showed in your question) keeps going if it gets an error while processing a given line.  That behavior can be changed according to the desire.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the program exited after processing 10 rows in csv. Could you please check.

Comment: do I need to change the status of the variable 'paused = false' to 'true' anywhere?

Comment: Its working for me. Need to run the full csv. Thanks

Comment: one more doubt, what is the maximum concurrent value I can give? any way to give dynamic value to 'maxConcurrent'. @jfriend00

Comment: @Dibish - You would have to run some experiments with different `maxConcurrent` values and measure total time to run to completion and peak memory usage.  It will depend a lot on the target host and how many simultaneous requests it can actually make progress on.  You want to set `maxConcurrent` as low as possible (which lowers peak memory usage) that doesn't make the total run time longer.  I picked a default of 10 as a guess that the target host could work on some parallel requests productively, but probably not more than 10 at a time.  You can tune it yourself.

Comment: @Dibish -  I want to emphasize that the best range of values for `maxConcurrent` is dependent upon the target host and how many simultaneous requests it can productively work on.  A giant server farm that has tons of horizontal scaling and doesn't route your requests always to the same host might be able to process a lot of simultaneous requests.  A non-horizontally scaled server that has a small database bottleneck for each request might not benefit from more than 2 or 3 simultaneous requests.  And, some hosts may have rate limiting limits too that also influence your choice.

Comment: @Dibish - Also, you don't have to find a perfect number for `maxConcurrent`.  If you make it larger than it needs to be (where you aren't gaining end-to-end runtime improvements), you just increase your peak memory usage higher than need be.  If you make it lower than it needs to be (where the target could handle more simultaneous requests), then you just slow down the end-to-end runtime a bit.  There's probably a wide range where peak memory usage is fine and end-to-end time is good.  The main point here is to NOT be all your requests in flight at once - to limit it to a modest number.